# Tracing Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working with Java 8 streams, and would like to come up with a way to debug them. So i thought I could write a filter that printed out the elements at a stage of the stream, something like this:

```
int[] nums = {3, -4, 8, 4, -2, 17, 9, -10, 14, 6, -12};
int sum = Arrays.stream(nums)
    .filter(w -> {System.out.print(" " + w); return true;}) // trace
    .map(n -> Math.abs(n))
    .filter(w -> {System.out.print(" " + w); return true;}) // trace
    .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
    .distinct()
    .sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Close, but that's not quite it, as it doesn't have the proper delimiters to make it legible:

```
 3 3 -4 4 8 8 4 4 -2 2 17 17 9 9 -10 10 14 14 6 6 -12 1256
```

What I want is:

```
[3, -4, 8, 4, -2, 17, 9, -10, 14, 6, -12]
[3 4 8 4 2 17 9 10 14 6 12]
56
```

Is there a more standard way to do this? Note that Peek as the linked article says does not do this, because I somehow want to collect all the elements of the stream at each stage together.

Comment: You're looking for the `peek` operation, check the linked question.

Comment: Peek would not do the job. I've added some more detail to my question. It's def not a dup!

Comment: Ah yes. But this is not how it works: the Stream is a single pipeline. Each element goes through to it from beginning until it is consumed. And repeat for the next one. To achieve what you want, you'd need to have multiple pipelines. A collect call consumes the whole stream and you can't process it again.

Comment: Ah that does make sense. Still for debugging it would be very handy to at least view it as stages while you are trying to get it to work. By the way, What's a collect call? You mean a terminator method (not sure of the terminology) like forEach() ? (also please unmark as dup?)

Comment: Yeah I reopened the question. Check the Stream tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/. By "collect call", I meant a terminal operation. You can also refer to the Stream API docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd need to use a different list for each checkpoint.

Normally I would not recommend using stream operations to mutate state in this way, but for debugging purposes I think it's ok. In fact, as @BrianGoetz points out below, debugging was the reason why `peek` was added.

```
int[] nums = {3, -4, 8, 4, -2, 17, 9, -10, 14, 6, -12};
List<Integer> checkPoint1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> checkPoint2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> checkPoint3 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> checkPoint4 = new ArrayList<>();
int sum = Arrays.stream(nums)
                .peek(checkPoint1::add)
                .map(n -> Math.abs(n))
                .peek(checkPoint2::add)
                .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
                .peek(checkPoint3::add)
                .distinct()
                .peek(checkPoint4::add)
                .sum();
System.out.println(checkPoint1);
System.out.println(checkPoint2);
System.out.println(checkPoint3);
System.out.println(checkPoint4);
System.out.println(sum);
```

Output:

```
[3, -4, 8, 4, -2, 17, 9, -10, 14, 6, -12]
[3, 4, 8, 4, 2, 17, 9, 10, 14, 6, 12]
[4, 8, 4, 2, 10, 14, 6, 12]
[4, 8, 2, 10, 14, 6, 12]
56
```

Comment: Clever. Seems like it does the job. But kinda ugly I am sure all would agree. It's probably the best we can do!

Comment: It's horrible. There is no easy way to debug this stuff unfortunately.

Comment: This is exactly why we added `peek()`.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks. I should have said that in my answer.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Like everything else, operation fusion is a tradeoff.  99+% of the time, you like the performance it gives you; some small percentage of the time, it gets in the way of figuring out what's going on, and then you break out some (often crufty or intrusive) tools to inspect what's going on.  (Declarative query languages are always like that; SQL implementations need tools to inspect query plans and table statistics so we can see what's going on when we code the query wrong.)

Answer (score 6):

If you find yourself needing Paul's solution *very often* then one could write a static wrapper function that generates indexed peek functions:

```
int sum = streamDebugger<Integer>((Supplier<Consumer<?>> peekGen) => {
   return Arrays.stream(nums)
                .peek(peekGen.get())
                .map(n -> Math.abs(n))
                .peek(peekGen.get())
                .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
                .peek(peekGen.get())
                .distinct()
                .peek(peekGen.get())
                .sum();
})
```

To automate this one step further one could even wrap the entire stream interface(s) so that each defined interface method again returns a wrapped implementation that automatically does the peeking for each step in the pipeline:

```
int sum = debugIntStream(Arrays.stream(nums))
                .map(n -> Math.abs(n))
                .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
                .distinct()
                .sum();
```

Since the implementation would be fairly tedious and hopefully not necessary the implementation is left to the reader.